# Run script after container entrypoint in docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a postgres:9.5.6-alpine container, and another container, named web, which has to be linked to it.
I want to run a script named `create_db.sh` in postgres container after it has been started and docker-entrypoint.sh has been executed, in order to create a db and a user and restore a backup.
My `docker-compose.yml` (postgres part):

```
  postgres:
    build: ./postgres
    container_name: postgres
    volumes:
      - /shared_folder/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"    
    command:  sh /home/create_db.sh
```

The content of `create_db.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/sh

psql -d template1 -U postgres
psql --command "CREATE USER user WITH PASSWORD 'userpassword';" 
psql --command "CREATE DATABASE userdb;"
psql --command "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE userdb to user;"
psql --command "\q;"  
psql -U user -d userdb -f /var/lib/postgresql/backup.sql

exit
```

When i run `docker-compose build` and then `docker-compose up` i get this:

```
Attaching to postgres, web
postgres    | psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
postgres    |   Is the server running locally and accepting
postgres    |   connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I've understood this is because when I launch `create_db.sh` postgres server is not ready, but so how can i run it after the `docker-entrypoint.sh` of the container?

Comment: I think you should add content of `create_db.sh` file inside `docker-entrypoint.sh` . This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are overriding the original `command` and you do not start postgres in this script which is why your database is not available.

You can put your database initialization into the container's entrypoint directory: `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. This executes all `*.sh` and `*.sql` files in this directory and does not touch the original `command`.
All files in this directory are automatically executed in the alphabetical order on *container creation*. Therefore, create a volume to add your scripts / sql files to the entrypoint and let the container execute them. This is described in the official postgres documentation, section ["How to extend this image"](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/).

Your compose file then changes to something like this:

```
postgres:
  build: ./postgres
  volumes:
    - /shared_folder/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
    - ./db-init-scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
```

whereas a local directory, e.g. `db-init-scripts`, contains your initialization scripts (rename it if you want). Copy `create_db.sh` to this folder and it will be automatically executed when you create a new container.

Several database-images watch this entrypoint-directory, which is very convenient.

Your `container_name: postgres` seems redundant.

Comment: how to run instead a .sh script on container START ?

Comment: Add your shell script via `COPY` or as a volume binding and execute it as your `command`. But postgres directly supports executing shell scripts when they are located under `/docker-entrypoint-initdb` (see https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres "Initialization scripts")

Comment: Getting `/bin/sh: bad interpreter: Permission denied` when trying to run script by postgres container, was anyone able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an error `/bin/sh: bad interpreter: Permission denied` change execution permission to your script file first, since Docker copies over permissions:

```
chmod +x your/script.sh
```