# How to specify the current working database for the initialization script of a postgres docker container?

Tags: postgresql, docker

It is known that one can copy an init.sql file to be executed on the creation of the container with a docker command similar to this one: `COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`

Let's consider that one uses a very simple create table postgresql statement:

```
CREATE TABLE films (
  code        char(5) CONSTRAINT firstkey PRIMARY KEY,
  title       varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  did         integer NOT NULL,
  date_prod   date,
  kind        varchar(10),
  len         interval hour to minute
);
```

The question is **where** (in which database) is this table created?

But more importantly is **how to set the current working database** to specify exactly on which database we are working with??
*Not only for this statement but also for all subsequent ones, and they are many!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This explains in detail the initialization of the database. [How to create User/Database in script for Docker Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598738/how-to-create-user-database-in-script-for-docker-postgres).

To put it briefly, the name of the database created during the initialization and where your tables get created by default, is given by the environment variable `POSTGRES_DB`. If the variable is not set the default value `postgres` is used instead.

The scripts in the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` folder are executed one by one with the following command:

```
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" -f <your-file>
```

therefore you are connected to the `POSTGRES_DB` database (have a look at the `docker-entrypoint.sh` script).

In your script files you can nevertheless connect to a different database using the meta-command

```
\connect DBNAME
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy: set an environment variable `POSTGRES_DB`.

According to the [docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres):

> This optional environment variable can be used to define a different name for the default database that is created when the image is first started. If it is not specified, then the value of POSTGRES_USER will be used.