# Remote control on my postgresql container docker works but can't see tables creates

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile

I am new in docker, I've created a dockerfile to launch postgresql image and insert data in a new database.

When I run docker it works well in its container, I can see database and tables created.

But When I try to connect from a client postgres, I see the database created but not tables and we dont know why me and my team..

My DockerFile:

```sh
# Dockerfile
FROM postgres:9.6.5
RUN localedef -i fr_FR -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias fr_FR.UTF-8
ENV LANG fr_FR.utf8
COPY postgresql.conf /
COPY sql/structure.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

My file SQL structure.sql:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE DB_ALLOT_BOUCHON_NEW;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE DB_ALLOT_BOUCHON_NEW TO postgres;
CREATE Table IF NOT EXISTS public.SUBSCR (
    ID              BIGINT       NOT NULL,
    subscriber_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    sp_array        VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

INSERT INTO SUBSCR (ID, subscriber_name, sp_array) VALUES (1, 'client_1', 'sp_array client_1 client_2');
INSERT INTO SUBSCR (ID, subscriber_name, sp_array) VALUES (2, 'client_2', 'sp_array client_2 client_2');
```

Command to build and run my dockerfile:

```sh
$ docker build -t allot_psql .
$ docker run -d --name custom_psql_running -p 5467:5432 allot_psql -c config_file=postgresql.conf
$ docker logs custom_psql_running
$ docker run -it --rm --link custom_psql_running postgres psql -h custom_psql_running -U postgres
# postgres=# SELECT * from subscr;
```

Result in my container:

```sql
postgres=# select * from subscr;
 id | subscriber_name |          sp_array
----+-----------------+----------------------------
  1 | client_1        | sp_array client_1 client_2
  2 | client_2        | sp_array client_2 client_2
(2 rows)

postgres=# \d
         List of relations
 Schema |  Name  | Type  |  Owner
--------+--------+-------+----------
 public | subscr | table | postgres
(1 row)

postgres=# \d*
Invalid command \d*. Try \? for help.
postgres=# \dt
         List of relations
 Schema |  Name  | Type  |  Owner
--------+--------+-------+----------
 public | subscr | table | postgres
(1 row)

postgres=# \d+
                       List of relations
 Schema |  Name  | Type  |  Owner   |    Size    | Description
--------+--------+-------+----------+------------+-------------
 public | subscr | table | postgres | 8192 bytes |
(1 row)

postgres=# \d
         List of relations
 Schema |  Name  | Type  |  Owner
--------+--------+-------+----------
 public | subscr | table | postgres
(1 row)

postgres=# \
Invalid command \. Try \? for help.
postgres=# \q
```

Everything seems to work well but when I use postgresql client, I can see only the database created but not tables inside.

```sql
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5467/db_allot_bouchon_new
username:postgres
```

Answer (score 3):

The `structure.sql` script creates the tables in the default database `postgres` and not in `DB_ALLOT_BOUCHON_NEW`. When the container is initialized you are connected to postgres.To quickly fix connect to `db_allot_bouchon_new` right after you create it

```
CREATE DATABASE DB_ALLOT_BOUCHON_NEW;
\connect db_allot_bouchon_new
 ...
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50411107/8482479) may help as well.

Comment: Thanks a  lot i was totally blind and didnt see my mistake, lost 2 days..

Comment: You're weIcome, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to set `POSTGRES_DB`  environment variable in your Dockerfile so this will create DB and Container will treat this DB as a default DB.

**POSTGRES_DB**

> This optional environment variable can be used to define a different
>   name for the default database that is created when the image is first
>   started. If it is not specified, then the value of `POSTGRES_USER` will
>   be used.

## Dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:latest
RUN localedef -i fr_FR -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias fr_FR.UTF-8
ENV LANG fr_FR.utf8
ENV POSTGRES_DB="db_allot_bouchon_new"
# To set user and pass but better to pass at run time
ENV POSTGRES_USER="appdbuser"  
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD="123123"

COPY sql/structure.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

In the above Dockerfile, this will create user `appdbuser`.

`docker exec -it custom_psql_running bash -c " psql -U appdbuser"`

So you will not need to mention these two lines in SQL script as Docker image will do that for you. So better to remove these line.

```
CREATE DATABASE DB_ALLOT_BOUCHON_NEW;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE DB_ALLOT_BOUCHON_NEW TO postgres;
```

**Warning:**

> scripts in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d are only run if you start the
>   container with a data directory that is empty; any pre-existing
>   database will be left untouched on container startup. One common
>   problem is that if one of your /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d scripts
>   fails (which will cause the entrypoint script to exit) and your
>   orchestrator restarts the container with the already initialized data
>   directory, it will not continue on with your scripts.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advices and now it works ! Great !